# CSV file uploading as C:\xampp\tmp\phpBAED.tmp

Tags: php, mysql, csv, symfony

I am using symfony and I am trying to upload csv a file that contains emails
but it's uploading as C:\xampp\tmp\phpBAED.tmp
(I am a beginner so I'd  very much appreciate the help )

```
 $emails = new Emails(); 
 $errors = $validator->validate($emails);

 $form = $this->createForm(EmailsType::class); 
     $form->handleRequest($request); 

      if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
      { 
         
          $emails = $form->getData(); 
           $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $entityManager->persist($emails); 
                     
           $entityManager->flush(); 
           $this->addFlash('success', 'emails saved');
           return $this->redirectToRoute('groupe_mail'); 

         }
```

Emailstype :

```
  $builder
       ->add('Email',FileType::class)
        ->add('idGroupe')
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
```

Comment: What does the form definition look like?

Comment: just added it ↑ ↑

Comment: Form definition looks ok but you have no file handling at all in your controller.

Comment: well its even saved in my database as "C:\xampp\tmp\php222D.tmp" instead of saving the content of the file

Comment: Check the documentation for example of how to handle uploaded files: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Comment: `File::__toString()` returns the path to the file, that's what you're seeing in your database. Do you want to store the actual file contents in your database? As already mentioned, you'll have to process the file yourself. And on a side note, you don't really need the first two lines.

Comment: well I added some code and it stores the contents now but WITH the contents it stores the path of the file too